# Android Image not switching

Tags: android, menu, imageswitcher

I'm working on a piece of code that could switch image using Menu inflater, i've worked on code but it gives me force close error as soon as i click the button. here is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cameraa:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Start Camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case R.id.gallery:
         Toast.makeText(this, "this is gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


    case R.id.ghost_gallery:
            switcher.showNext();
break
            }
            return true;
        }
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/banana" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/apple" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </ViewSwitcher>
```

here is my log

```
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at org.example.touch.Touch.nextView(Touch.java:188)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at org.example.touch.Touch.onOptionsItemSelected(Touch.java:180)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2195)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-21 03:19:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(758):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Kindly help me regarding this matter....
Best Regards,

Comment: @Simon find my logcat please..i've edited my ans

Comment: switcher is not initialized and still null.

Comment: i'm using two other case, and they are working perfectly, just giving me force close error when i click on that button

Comment: Can you post the code where you declared the variable switcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used

```
private void showImage() {

        Toast.makeText(Touch.this, " User don't  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[image_index]);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case (R.id.previous_btn):

            image_index--;

            if (image_index == -1) {
                image_index = MAX_IMAGE_COUNT - 1;
            }

            showImage();
            break;
}}
```

which works pretty well for me...

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's easy: `switcher` is `null`. Is to be expected since it doesn't even has an id in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize switcher in onCreate()?

You need to give it an id in the layout:

```
android:id="@+id/switcher_view"
```

Declare ViewSwitcher outside any methods as switcher:

```
private ViewSwitcher switcher;
```

Then initialize it like this (in onCreate()):

```
switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher_view);
```

Comment: yup.. i've initialized it too

Comment: And its still throwing an exception at the same line in your code? Or do you mean it was initialized all along? How did you do that while ViewSwitcher did not have an id?

Comment: i've used Toast message to verify its working, then apply image switcher to it...it gives me force close error

Comment: Are you sure there is no stack trace visible in logcat when the force close occurs?

Comment: I am sorry. My answer was misleading. If you have declared switcher as a member variable of the class you must not declare it again in onCreate(). I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Jackel i'm new to android... and would apreciate if you can help me how to acheive the task..i've edited my ans...the other two cases are working perfectly..but the third one gives me error....

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give your `ViewSwitcher` an ID. And also you need to use `findViewById` to refer to it in your other code.